# Why does my cat fart a lot?

Tags: cats, health

My cat farts a lot. In addition, his belly seems tight, like he's full of gas.

Should I be concerned about this flatulence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Persistent flatulence is not normal. While an occasional fart is nothing to be concerned about, if it's happening daily then your cat should see a veterinarian.

Flatulence can have several different causes and only your vet can determine the cause for your cat.

- Overgrowth of the certain kinds of gut bacteria
- Intolerance to certain types of foods
- Irritable Bowel Disease (the intestines don't properly absorb food)
- Or other similar Gastrointestinal system problems.

Your vet may prescribe some over the counter medications to try, may do some bloodwork, and may recommend a biopsy to determine the cause of the flatulence.

Untreated GI problems can lead to malnutrition and discomfort for your pet, so it is important to get your cat to a veterinarian for proper care.